# AWS DynamoDB Auto Scaling. Provisioned range for reads. How to setup the range in Terraform script?

Tags: terraform, amazon-dynamodb

The code as follows gives me the output of "Provisioned range for reads" as 5 - 10 in the Additional settings, Read/write capacity. I would like to set it as 1 - 10. How to do it?

```
module "dynamodb_table" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/dynamodb-table/aws"
  version  = "3.1.1"

  name                = var.dbname
  hash_key            = var.hash_key
  billing_mode        = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity       = 5
  write_capacity      = 1
  autoscaling_enabled = true

  autoscaling_read = {
    scale_in_cooldown  = 50
    scale_out_cooldown = 40
    target_value       = 70
    min_capacity       = 1
    max_capacity       = 10
  }

  autoscaling_write = {
    scale_in_cooldown  = 50
    scale_out_cooldown = 40
    target_value       = 70
    min_capacity       = 1
    max_capacity       = 10
  }

  attributes = [
    {
      name = "user_id"
      type = "S"
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

Code from module:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "table_read" {
  count = var.create_table && var.autoscaling_enabled && length(var.autoscaling_read) > 0 ? 1 : 0

  max_capacity       = var.autoscaling_read["max_capacity"]
  min_capacity       = var.read_capacity
  resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.autoscaled[0].name}"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is the code from this reference:

- [aws_appautoscaling_target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_target)
- [aws_appautoscaling_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_policy)

Here is my implementation from `main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
  name           = var.table_name
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = var.read_capacity_target
  write_capacity = var.write_capacity_target
  hash_key       = var.partition_key_name
  range_key      = var.sort_key_name
  ttl            = var.ttl
  point_in_time_recovery { enabled = true }
  server_side_encryption { enabled = true }
  lifecycle {ignore_changes = [read_capacity, write_capacity]}
  attribute {
    name = var.partition_key_name
    type = var.partition_key_type
  }
  attribute {
    name = var.sort_key_name
    type = var.sort_key_type
  }
  tags = {
    "Environment"  = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dynamodb_table_read_target" {
  max_capacity       = var.read_capacity_maximum
  min_capacity       = var.read_capacity_minimum
  resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.table.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dynamodb_table_read_policy" {
  name               = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id}"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 70.0
  }
}
```

And here is the `variables.tf` code:

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  description = "Required. The Virtual Private Network containing all services."
  type    = string
}
variable "table_name" {
  description = "Required. The name of the DDB table. No spaces."
  type    = string
}
variable "partition_key_name" {
  description = "Required. Name of the partition key. No spaces."
  type    = string
}
variable "partition_key_type" {
  description = "Required. Partition key type: 'S' or 'N'"
  type    = string
}
variable "sort_key_name" {
  description = "Required. The name of the Sort key. No spaces."
  type    = string
}
variable "sort_key_type" {
  description = "Required. Sort key type: 'S' or 'N'"
  type    = string
}
variable "ttl" {
  description = "Required. True if TTL or time-to-live is enabled"
  type    = bool
}

variable "read_capacity_maximum" {
  description = "Required. Maximum allowed autoscale range."
  type    = number
  default = 10
}
variable "read_capacity_minimum" {
  description = "Required. Minimum allowed autoscale range."
  type    = number
  default = 2
}
variable "read_capacity_target" {
  description = "Required. Target within autoscale range."
  type    = number
  default = 5
}
variable "write_capacity_maximum" {
  description = "Required. Maximum allowed autoscale range."
  type    = number
  default = 10
}
variable "write_capacity_minimum" {
  description = "Required. Minimum allowed autoscale range."
  type    = string
  default = 2
}
variable "write_capacity_target" {
  description = "Required. Target within autoscale range."
  type    = number
  default = 5
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "The staging type: development, production."
  default = "development"
  type    = string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is your read_capacity is your min used for autoscaling and your max is defined within your autoscaling module.

Try this:

```
module "dynamodb_table" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/dynamodb-table/aws"
  version  = "3.1.1"

  name                = var.dbname
  hash_key            = var.hash_key
  billing_mode        = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity       = 1
  write_capacity      = 1
  autoscaling_enabled = true

  autoscaling_read = {
    scale_in_cooldown  = 50
    scale_out_cooldown = 40
    target_value       = 70
    max_capacity       = 10
  }

  autoscaling_write = {
    scale_in_cooldown  = 50
    scale_out_cooldown = 40
    target_value       = 70
    max_capacity       = 10
  }

  attributes = [
    {
      name = "user_id"
      type = "S"
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

If that fails try something like the following:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dynamodb-test-table_read_target" {
    max_capacity       = 10
    min_capacity       = 1
    resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb-test-table.name}"
    scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
    service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}
```

Comment: I added min_capacity       = 1.  It still shows "Provisioned range for reads" as 5 - 10.

Comment: Did you suggest to change the module? I cannot simply place your code into my code. I think it is a bug.  See the code I got from the module.
```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "table_read" {
  count = var.create_table && var.autoscaling_enabled && length(var.autoscaling_read) > 0 ? 1 : 0

  max_capacity       = var.autoscaling_read["max_capacity"]
  min_capacity       = var.read_capacity
  resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.autoscaled[0].name}"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}
```

Comment: The code I pasted in the comment is not in good format. I pasted the code in my question.

Comment: Edited my code block. Try the first one.

Comment: No luck. The version is version  = "3.1.2". Still same problem. Can you please try my code?